# Automatically delete services after a set period of time

Tags: arcgis-server, workflow

Is it possible to automatically delete services after a set period of time? Is the username of the publishing user and the date the service was published saved anywhere? We are trying to implement a system to check for services that have been on the server for three months, identify the user that published them, and automatically email the user to find out if the service should be saved any longer. If yes, remind the user in another month. If no, delete the service. If no response, delete the service.

Any ideas for how to approach implementing this? Just looking for overall strategies here. Thanks

Comment: Which version your are using ? 10 or 10.1 ?? Because in 10.1 it may be possible using ArcGIS Admin. API..

Comment: 10.1... what are your ideas for using the Admin api?